# Making a defined spring bean primary

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have 3 beans of the same type defined in spring.xml. This is inside a jar file which I cannot edit. I want to make one of these primary in my spring-boot application using annotation. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Do those beans have a different name? You might be able to use it.

Comment: yes those beans have different names.

Comment: use `@Qualifier("beanName") `then

Comment: sorry , how could I make it primary with qualifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A straightforward approach is to use a bridge configuration, which will register the desired bean as a new primary bean. A simple example:

The interface:

```
public interface Greeter { String greet(); }
```

The configuration which you don't control:

```
@Configuration
public class Config1 {
    @Bean public Greeter british(){ return () -> "Hi"; }
    @Bean public Greeter obiWan(){ return () -> "Hello there"; }
    @Bean public Greeter american(){ return () -> "Howdy"; }
}
```

The bridge configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Config2 {
    @Primary @Bean public Greeter primary(@Qualifier("obiWan") Greeter g) { 
        return g; 
    }
}
```

The client code:

```
@RestController
public class ControllerImpl {
    @Autowired
    Greeter greeter;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test() {
        return greeter.greet();
    }
}
```

Result of `curl http://localhost:8080/test` will be

```
Hello there
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Qualifier("___beanName__")` annotation to choose the correct one

Comment: Thanks @JiriS.Using qualifier how could I make it primary?

Comment: I'm not sure if your goal is to use `@Primary` annotation for anything else than auto-wiring, but the main use of it is to indicate that the bean should be  primarily picked for auto-wiring (see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html).

Comment: The code for picking up the bean is inside one of the aspects in the jar which I cannot edit. So I want to make it primary.

Comment: If it's based only on `@Primary` annotation it might be a bit difficult and might involve some classpath magic. Otherwise it would help edit question and add this code to it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried [@jihor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5784273/jihor) solutions but it doesn't work. I have a `NullPointerException` in defined configuration.

Then I find the next solution on Spring Boot

```
@Configuration
public class Config1 {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.ddbb")
    public JndiPropertyHolder ddbbProperties() {
        return new JndiPropertyHolder();
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.datasource.ddbb.primary", matchIfMissing = false, havingValue = "true")
    @Bean("ddbbDataSource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource ddbbDataSourcePrimary() {
        return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource(ddbbProperties().getJndiName());
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.datasource.ddbb.primary", matchIfMissing = true, havingValue = "false")
    @Bean("ddbbDataSource")
    public DataSource ddbbDataSource() {
        return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource(ddbbProperties().getJndiName());
    }
}
```

And my **application.properties** if I need this datasource as primary, otherwise don't set the property or set false.

```
spring.datasource.ddbb.primary=true
```